# How is the binomial distribution connected with the theoretical approach to probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've been told the theoretical approach to probability is defined as follows

$$\operatorname{Pr}(\textsf{something})=\frac{\textsf{Favorable events}}{\textsf{possible events}}$$

This has to be connected to the binomial distribution given by the formula:

$$b(x;n,p)={}_nC_x(1-p)^{n-x}(p)^{x}$$

I think it's connected because I've taken combinations here. ${}_nC_x$ tells me all the different ways to create my favorable event. What I can't prove to myself is how $(1-p)^{n-x}(p)^{x}$ would be $$\frac{\textsf{Favorable event}}{\textsf{possible events}}$$ Note I've taken away the `s` from `favorable events`, because my combinations operator will make that plural for me.

I'm sorry if my question is unclear, but I want to figure this out.

In case you're wondering what my actual question is, it is this one:

How is the binomial distribution similar to the theoretical approach? How is $$(1-p)^{n-x}(p)^{x}=\frac{\textsf{Favorable event}}{\textsf{possible events}}?$$

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK you can only use your 'theoretical approach' when all your 'basic events' are equally likely. For the Binomial this corresponds to the $p=1/2$ case, in which case you have $(1-p)^{n-x}p^x = 1/2^n$. This matches with 1 = the number of ways  you can get $n-x$ failures followed by $p$ successes (or any permutation of these failures and successes) and 2^n = the number of $n$-tuples of failures and successes.

Comment: I think the incentive to want to take combinations has to be somehow related to the "theoretical approach" for all cases of p.

Comment: You likely can't get it for all values of $p$, I'm confident that there is an irrational $p$ so that $(1−p)^{n−x}p^x$ is irrational, so there is no hope of having it in the form $\frac{\text{number of favourable events}}{\text{total number of events}} ∈ \mathbb{Q}$ in this case.

Comment: e.g., choose $p = 2^{1/(n+1)}/10$.

Also $\binom{n}{x}$ doesn't come from the 'theoretical approach', it comes from asking 'how many ways are there to have $x$ successes and $n-x$ failures'? Each success then happens with probability p independently and each failure with probability (1-p).

If you are searching for a solid foundation for probability, I'm afraid that this is not the solution. The right place to look is measure theory, and if that is too far ahead, Andrey's answer where you build a binomial out of Bernoullis is a reasonable compromise IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Binomial coefficient dont have just the meaning of "combinations". The MAIN meaning of any factorial is **number of permutations** (and have a close relation too with the number of derivatives of powers, in the more general sense of falling factorial).

Binomial coefficient count the permutations with fixed repetitions between two 2 groups of identical things (in some abstract level of interpretation).

You can understand this easily if, I said above, you interpret any factorial as number of permutations (or elimination of repeated permutations if they are in the denominator).

See that

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

- $n!$ are the permutations of $n$ objects over $n$ positions
- $k!$ are the permutations of $k$ objects over $k$ positions. In the denominator it means that you are **eliminating** the permutations of the $k$ objects because they are identical and dont lead to different sequences.
- $(n-k)!$ is the same case for $k$ but for identical number of objects $(n-k)$

The general is the multinomial coefficient that make the same thing but instead of just two kind of objects it do for more than just two groups.

The multinomial coefficient $\binom{n}{a,b,c}=\frac{n!}{a!b!c!}$, where $a+b+c=n$, represent the number of different sequences of length $n$ for 3 groups of objects $a,b,c$.

In general

$$\binom{n}{k_1,k_2,k_3,...,k_n}=\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!\cdots k_n!};\ k_1+k_2+k_2+...+k_n=n$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what's confusing you, so hopefully this sheds some light.

Recall that a Bernoulli trial is an experiment with exactly two outcomes: either one success $S$, or one failure $F$. A binomial distribution is just a series of Bernoulli trials.

Each sample point in the sample space of a binomial distribution can be expressed an $n$-tuple of $S$'s and $F$'s:

$$\underbrace{SSFSFFSSSF \cdots SSFF}_\text{n positions}.$$

Now consider a sample point corresponding to $x$ successes and $n-x$ failures:

$$\underbrace{SSS\cdots SS}_\text{x successes} \  \underbrace{FFF\cdots FF}_\text{n-x failures}.$$

The above sample point represents the intersection of $n$ independent events (since they're Bernoulli trials). Since they're independent, the probability of a success $S$ stays at a uniform $p$. So the probability of the above sample point is:

$$P(\underbrace{SSS\cdots SS}_\text{x successes} \  \underbrace{FFF\cdots FF}_\text{n-x failures}) = P(S) \cdots P(S) \ P(F) \cdots P(F)$$
$$\underbrace{ppp\cdots pp}_\text{x terms} \  \underbrace{qqq\cdots qq}_\text{n-x terms} = p^x (1-p)^{n-x}.$$

The above is one favorable event. However there are many favorable events *(having $x$ successes among $n$ trials)*. In particular, there are $n \choose x$ ways of **choosing** $x$ successes among $n$ trials.

By the multiplication principle, we have $$p(x) = {n \choose x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}.$$

Comment: I do understand that. The fact that we want to take combinations is not entirely obvious if it weren't for the "theoretical approach" I mentioned. I wanted to know if there's any fundamental relationship between that approach and this formula. Thanks though.

Comment: Our favorable event is to have $x$ successes and $n-x$ failures though. Since we already have the probability of a success $p$ from one Bernoulli trial, we don't have to go through the theoretical approach.